# Emit a call to a lambda expression

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

When I try a call on a lambda expression I get an exception. It seems to be realted to the fact that the lambda generates a private static method. How can I achieve what I want ?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var typeBuilder = CreateTypeBuilder();
        AddStaticMethodAsAProperty(typeBuilder, "StaticPublic", Return1);
        AddStaticMethodAsAProperty(typeBuilder, "StaticPrivate", Return2);
        AddStaticMethodAsAProperty(typeBuilder, "Lambda", () => 3);

        var newType = typeBuilder.CreateType();
        dynamic newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(newType);
        var resultFromStatic = newObject.StaticPublic; //Ok
        var resultFromStaticPrivate = newObject.StaticPrivate; //Additional information: Attempt by method 'NewType.get_StaticPrivate()' to access method 'Test.Program.Return2()' failed.
        var resultFromLambda = newObject.Lambda; //failed with Additional information: Attempt by method 'NewType.get_Lambda()' to access method 'Test.Program.<Main>b__3()' failed.
    }

    public static void AddStaticMethodAsAProperty(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, string propertyName, Func<int> methodToAdd)
    {
        var propertyType = methodToAdd.Method.ReturnType;

        var getPropertyMethodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(string.Format("get_{0}", propertyName), MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);

        var getIL = getPropertyMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

        getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, methodToAdd.Method);
        getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.None, propertyType, new Type[] { });
        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropertyMethodBuilder);
    }

    public static int Return1()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    private static int Return2()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    private static TypeBuilder CreateTypeBuilder()
    {
        var newTypeName = "NewType";
        var newAssemblyName = new AssemblyName(newTypeName);
        var assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(newAssemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
        var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(newTypeName
                                            , TypeAttributes.Public |
                                            TypeAttributes.Class |
                                            TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
                                            TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
                                            TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
                                            TypeAttributes.AutoLayout
                                            , null);
        return typeBuilder;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you intend to put in the lambda? The generated class can't access any private data in your original generating assembly, so only trivial lambdas would even work. Do you need to generate a separate assembly and class here or do you have a scenario that building expression trees could help you solve instead?

Comment: Yeah, what are you trying to do here? Build a proxy class in runtime or something?

Comment: @Luaan : yes this is what I am trying to achieve. At run time, I want to create a type whose the getter are "routed" as I defined it at compile time.

Comment: You may be interested in [DynamicObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject), [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) or, if you like rolling your own, [RealProxy](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2010/07/17/Creating-proxies-with-RealProxy.aspx). Although it's certainly possible to create a class from scratch with `Reflection.Emit`, you're basically redoing the work of the C# compiler -- not fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I wanted to do, idea is to keep track of the function as field and then calling this field in the getter.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var typeBuilder = CreateTypeBuilder();
        AddStaticMethodAsAProperty(typeBuilder, "StaticPublic", Return1);
        AddStaticMethodAsAProperty(typeBuilder, "StaticPrivate", Return2);
        AddStaticMethodAsAProperty(typeBuilder, "Lambda", () => 3);

        var newType = typeBuilder.CreateType();

        dynamic newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(newType);
        foreach (var onNewObjectCreated in _onNewObjectCreated)
        {
            onNewObjectCreated(newObject);
        }

        var resultFromStatic = newObject.StaticPublic; //Ok 1
        var resultFromStaticPrivate = newObject.StaticPrivate; //Ok 2
        var resultFromLambda = newObject.Lambda; //Ok 3
    }

    private static List<Action<object>> _onNewObjectCreated = new List<Action<object>>();
    public static void AddStaticMethodAsAProperty<T>(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, string propertyName, Func<T> valueGetter)
    {
        var propertyType = valueGetter.Method.ReturnType;
        var delegateFieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField(string.Format("_backingDelegate{0}", propertyName), valueGetter.GetType(), FieldAttributes.Private);

        var getMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(string.Format("get_{0}", propertyName), MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);


        Action<object> setDelegateFieldAction = newlyCreatedObject => { newlyCreatedObject.GetType().GetField(delegateFieldBuilder.Name, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(newlyCreatedObject, valueGetter); };
        _onNewObjectCreated.Add(setDelegateFieldAction);

        var il = getMethod.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);//stack [this]
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, delegateFieldBuilder);//stack [this._backingDelegateXXX]
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, valueGetter.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke"));//stack [valueReturnedByTheDelegate]
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        var propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.None, propertyType, new Type[] { });
        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getMethod);
    }

    public static int Return1()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    private static int Return2()
    {
        return 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`methodToAdd` is a delegate. You're trying to call the `Method` it internally contains, but that's the wrong approach. You want to execute the delegate instead, and that's a bit more complicated.

Basically, you need to call the `Invoke` method on `methodToAdd`. Which also means you need to put the delegate somewhere accessible from the final code. In other words, you need to do a lot of the work that the C# compiler usually does - create anonymous classes that contain a reference to the delegate. Calling `callvirt Func<int>.Invoke` on that reference is the easy part.

Thankfully, the new `Expression` stuff is completely awesome. So you should be able to do this:

```
Expression<Func<T>> expr = () => methodToAdd();
expr.CompileToMethod(getPropertyMethodBuilder);
```

Always try to stay away as far as possible from emitting IL - even `ilasm` itself is doing a lot of work that `ILGenerator` doesn't. But it still has to produce valid IL - and `call` on a private method in the wrong scope certainly *isn't* valid IL.